# Problems with dissolved shapefiles in Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, dissolve, geemap

I created a single dissolved polygon shapefile out of a set of smaller polygons in ArcGIS and imported it into Google Earth Engine using geemap (Python API). I wanted to extract values from every pixel in the dissolved shapefile using the `ee.Image.sampleRegions` function.

However, upon closer inspection, it appears that the function only sampled one of the smaller polygons, even though I imported it as a single shapefile. When I show it on the map and select it, it seems like it should be working as a single polygon.

Does anyone know why this could be? It is a large area (about 20,000 hectares), if that matters.